# error C3867 C++

Tags: c++

```
for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                if (strcmp(c[i].c_str, c[j].c_str) > 0) {    //error C3867
                    swap(c[i], c[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Пишет
error C3867:"std::basic_string,std::allocator>::c_str"
Динамические переменные не использую, нужно отсортировать массив строк c[100] в алфавитном порядке.

Comment: Полагаю, c_str это функция, а у вас () - нет. c_str()

Comment: Зачем вообще использовать strcmp со строками, когда std::string можно сравнивать операторами сравнения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strcmp(c[i].c_str())
```

`c_str()` функция.

Comment: Ответ дублирует уже сказанное ранее.

Answer (score 1):

WierdGreenCat

> c_str это функция, а у вас ()

прав, спасибо.